# Arraylist IndexOutOfBounds Debugging error

Tags: java, debugging, arraylist

I am getting the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.set(Unknown Source)
    at shortestPath.runQ5(shortestPath.java:181)
    at shortestPath.main(shortestPath.java:26)
```

The code which is giving that issues is as follows:

```
 public ArrayList<Integer[]> runQ5() throws Exception   
   {        
       int oldPathCost = 0, pathCost = 0;
       ArrayList<Integer[]> temporary = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();       

       for(int i=1; i<stationNames.size(); i++)
       {
           for(int j=1; j<stationNames.size() & i != j; j++)
           {
               pathCost = runQ3(stationNames.ceilingKey(i), stationNames.ceilingKey(j));

               if(pathCost > oldPathCost)
               {
                   System.out.println(i + ", " + j + ", " +temporary.size());
                   oldPathCost = pathCost;
                   temporary.set(temporary.size(), new Integer[]{i,j});
               }
               else if(pathCost == oldPathCost)
               {
                   oldPathCost = pathCost;
                   temporary.add(new Integer[]{i,j});
               }

           }
       }

       Q6 = oldPathCost + Q6;
       return temporary;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no point in :

```
temporary.set(temporary.size(), new Integer[]{i,j});
```

`set` is used to replace the value of an existing position in the list, but if the current size of the list is `temporary.size()`, the `temporary.size()`'th index is not yet occupied.

Just write :

```
temporary.add(new Integer[]{i,j});
```

if you want to set the `temporary.size()`'th element in the list.

Comment: Thank you and I am trying as told @Eran.